# Build number into published database?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

Can I somehow get a build number into an extended property of my published database?
I use SSDT Projects and tfs build.
I want to get as much information as possible into the database.
I know there are a few variables, such as database name. Perhaps there are more?

Even build date would be useful (timestamp from when the deployment script was created).
But ":setvar ts GETDATE()" won't work since the GETDATE not being evaluated.

EDIT: I got it working by editing the xaml and then using XmlPoke. I can post more details if there is interest.

Comment: You'd most likely need a variable, a post-deploy script that uses that variable, and something in your build/deploy process that passes that Build Number to that variable for use in publishing your changes. It's doable, but there's no "official" way to do this right now. I think Jamie Thomson had some ideas on his blog a while back, but it's not for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the mention Peter. Yes,I posited an idea around this at http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/01/01/implementing-sql-server-solutions-using-visual-studio-2010-database-projects-a-compendium-of-project-experiences.aspx. Hope its useful.

Comment: Thank's, but the problem is that the supplied values are not used, "/p:BuildId='123'" does not work with msbuild, so this is not applicable here. Please prove wrong if I am.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the build number to a post-deployment script that is updating the extended property

Comment: In the build definition I'm using this command to deploy the database: SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"Foo.dacpac" /TargetDatabaseName:"FooDB" /TargetServerName:"FooServer" /Variables:BuildNumber="FooBuildNumber" then in the post-deployment script I'm passing the BuildNumber variable to a stored procedure that is updating the extended property

Comment: OK, thank's, but I'm not using sqlpackage. We are using TFS Build definitions and variables seem not to be supported in tfsbuild.